# Duplicate entry '0' for key 1

Tags: hibernate

what does this exception mean?

> org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter:78 : logExceptions() : Duplicate entry '0' for key 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most surely, you didn't mark a field with its corresponding `auto-increment` value.

This way, when you try to make a new `INSERT`, it tries to save it with the default value for `integer` type fields, which is **0**. But you already have an item with the value '0', so it gives you the exception.

If you mark that field with auto-increment, it will take the last saved's `entry value + 1`.